# Using UIButton to navigate between views

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I programmatically added UIButtons to my views, but I can't make them do anything. If pressed, they don't take me to the next view, which they are supposed to do. Here is the code (sorry for the bad formatting):

```
let buttonMen   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
buttonMen.frame = CGRectMake(213, 108, 162, 306)
buttonMen.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(buttonMen)
```

My next view is called "General Information Page", while the connection between the two views is called "showGeneralInformation". So what do I need to add to the above code, if when I press the button, it takes me to the "General Information Page" view from my current view?

Comment: Can you show us the function btnTouched?

Comment: you need to perform the segue named "showGeneralInformation"

Comment: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showGeneralInformation", sender:buttonMen) - something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
func btnTouched(sender:UIButton!) {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showGeneralInformation", sender: self)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showGeneralInformation" {
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa59175beb0"

Comment: I also have multiple buttons. From your code snipped, how would I know which one was clicked?

Comment: @west123, multiple button with same function name or multiple segue?? I didn't get your question