# Xcode ios UIButton Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation

I am trying to make a ios app using xcode. I don't want to use the UIBarButton because I don't want the users to be able to go back. I tried following this previous post: [Using UIButton to navigate between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985761/using-uibutton-to-navigate-between-views) 
But it was not working for me.I have this for code:

```
`//MARK: Navigation
@IBAction func adClosure(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.prepareForSegue(segue: "adToMain", sender: self)

}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "adToMain" {

    }
}
```

The transition segue is called adToMain in my Main.storyboard. I have an error on the line with `self.prepareForSegue(segue: "adToMain", sender: self)`
because of mismatching argument types.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: It's `prepare(for:)` since Swift 3.

Comment: Just start typing prepare and Xcode will itself suggest the list of functions available. self.prepare(for: <#T##UIStoryboardSegue#>, sender: <#T##Any?#>) is the one you are looking for.

Comment: An advice : Don't copy paste the code. self.prepareForSegue(segue: "adToMain", sender: self) was in old Swift versions.

Comment: What's the version of Swift that you are using? Does the compiler suggest any fix?

Comment: @AhmadF I am doing it in xcode, but from my understanding it uses swift, so the newest version.